# Match and merge lines based on the first column

Tags: shell, unix

I have 2 files:

#### File1

```
123:dataset1:dataset932  
534940023023:dataset:dataset039302  
49930:dataset9203:dataset2003
```

#### File2

```
49930:399402:3949304:293000232:30203993  
123:49030:1204:9300:293920  
534940023023:49993029:3949203:49293904:29399
```

and I would like to create

### Desired result:

```
49930:399402:3949304:293000232:30203993:dataset9203:dataset2003  
534940023023:49993029:3949203:49293904:29399:dataset:dataset039302
etc
```

where the result contains one line for each pair of input lines that have identical first column (with `:` as the column separator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `join` command is your friend here.  You'll likely need to sort the inputs (either pre-sort the files, or use a process substitution if available - e.g. with `bash`).

Something like:

```
join -t ':' <(sort file2) <(sort file1) >file3
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do not want to sort files, play with grep:

```
while IFS=: read key others; do
        echo "${key}:${others}:$(grep "^${key}:" file1 | cut -d: -f2-)"
done < file2
```